# Is SQLAlchemy a database itself?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, rdbms

I am new to python but I have worked with ORM frameworks before. 
It is confusing for me that when I create database connection I can specify a database URL to some remote DB.
Or I can create DB in a file without remote DB. How does SQLAlchemy work with a file then?
It doesn`t have an RDBMS to connect to. Only file. So this is the reason for my question:
Is SQLAlchemy an RDBMS itself?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a database, but a library for handling databases, or [as they put it](https://www.sqlalchemy.org):

> SQLAlchemy is the Python SQL toolkit and Object Relational Mapper that gives application developers the full power and flexibility of SQL.

The file based [dialect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/) is [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html).